# where to mock in python

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I'm working with python for some years, and when it comes to unit testing and mocking I used to mock the collaborators of the unit under test where they are declared, for example if I want to mock a function called **my_function** declared in **my_module.py** module and used in my unit under test, I would write

```
@mock.patch('my_module.my_function')
def test_toast(mock_my_function):
    ...
```

and it works roughly all the times, but sometimes
it does not work until mocking it where it is used, for example supposing my unit under test is declared in **foo_module.py**, and it imports **my_function** from **my_module.py**
in order to mock  **my_function** I would write

```
@mock.patch('foo_module.my_function')
def test_toast(mock_my_function):
    ...
```

My first question is what the differences between the two methods of mocking in python ?, and when we should use each one ?

As far as my observations, they both work, but sometimes mocking where it's declared does not work.

Can you please help me to understand this behavior in details

Answer (score 1):

In short, it matters whether `toast`'s module uses

```
import foo

def toast():
    # use foo.my_function
```

or

```
from foo import my_function

def toast():
    # use my_function
```

In the former case, it doesn't matter what `foo` (and by extension, `foo.my_function`) refers to until you call `toast`, so you could use either `patch('foo.my_function')` or `patch('toast_module.foo.my_function')`, and `toast` will see the same patched value.

In the latter case, `toast_module.foo` is a new reference to `foo.my_function`, and that's the name used by `toast`. If you only patch `foo.my_function`, that doesn't affect `toast`, which itself doesn't access the module `foo` directly anymore.